# How to annotate maths equation in graph using both latex and f-String formatting

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, annotations, latex

Here's the code snippet : annotation of mathematical equation of the cuve.

```py
# equation annotation 
plt.annotate(s =f"$exp({poly_regr.intercept_[0] : 0.2f} - {-poly_regr.coef_[0,0] : 0.2f}x + {poly_regr.coef_[0,1]: 0.4f}x^2)$",
             xy = (1975, 0.4*(10**13)),
             color = "black",
             fontsize = 13,
             fontweight = "normal"
             )
```

[image]

what's the possible way to update the `f-string` code to get the desired anotation with a beautiful mathematical equations.
or even how to write more complex things , for example :[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using LaTeX syntax. For example, replace the string in `plt.annotate` with

```
fr"$e^{{({poly_regr.intercept_[0] : 0.2f} - {-poly_regr.coef_[0,0] : 0.2f}x + {poly_regr.coef_[0,1]: 0.4f}x^2)}}$"
```

or with

```
r"$e^{(\alpha + \beta + 48x)}$"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response.

Comment: `r"$e^{(\alpha + \beta + 48x)}$"` this works fine for the equation, could you help to add text with it too. Example : `r"$e^{(\alpha + \beta + 48x This is the equation)}$"`, the output is not giving the spacebar . `\text{This is not working}`. The alternative tedious way I know is `"\"` to put this after every word.